# Button onClick event is not executing when button in <div> tag is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have created a button in a div. The div is defined as:

```
<div id="popupdiv"title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none" >
```

In this div I have an asp button. When I click the button it doesn't call the onClick event in the code behind. But if I remove the style="display: none" it works. My code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Department.aspx.cs" Inherits="projectmfrp.Department" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<!--For Jquery-->
<title>Ad Department</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnclick').click(function () {
            $("#popupdiv").dialog({
                title: "Add Department",
                width: 430,
                height: 450,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
</script>
<!-- *******************************************************-->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <!--*************for Jquery*********************-->
    <!-- <form id="form1">-->
    <div>
        <div id="popupdiv"title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequiredValidator" 
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="AddDeptEmailTextBox"
                            ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Email can't be Blank">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AddDepartmentNameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text="Department Name">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AddDepartmentTextBox" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AddDepartnameRequired" 
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="AddDepartmentTextBox"
                            ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Can't be Blank">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AddReportingManager" runat="server" 
                            Text="Reporting Manager">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="AddReportingManagerDDL" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AddDeptContactNoLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text="Contact Number">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AddDeptContactNoTextBox" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AddContactValidator" 
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="AddDeptContactNoTextBox"
                            ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Can't be Blank">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AddEmailLabel" runat="server" Text="Email">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AddDeptEmailTextBox" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="AddEmailCompareValidator" 
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="AddDeptEmailTextBox"
                            ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Must be like abc@def.com"
                            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AddDeptInfoLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text="Department Information">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AddDeptInfoTextBox" runat="server" >
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="AddDepartmentButton" runat="server" 
                            Text="Save" onclick="AddDepartmentButton_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </div>
        <table align="right">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="AddDepartmentLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text="Add New Department">
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnclick" value="+" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!--</form>-->
    <!--*************for Jquery*********************-->
    <asp:GridView ID="ViewDepartmentGridView" runat="server" width="100%" 
        AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
        onrowcancelingedit="ViewDepartmentGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="ViewDepartmentGridView_RowDeleting" 
        onrowediting="ViewDepartmentGridView_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="ViewDepartmentGridView_RowUpdating">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: So you are trying to click on something that isn't visible?

Comment: `<div id="popupdiv"title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none" >` If you remove this from your code, what is happening..?!?

Comment: @balachandran, OP says it works if he removes `display:none`, I'm curious how he is "clicking" on the button that isn't displayed.

Comment: Actually this div is pop out when i clicked on a another button on my page And the button for which i am talking about is in the div

Comment: @user3760172, so at some point it is being made visible. Can you show the onclick event you are using?

Comment: @smerny,    Yes that time it is working fine

Comment: @smerny,@balachandran I have submitted the code please check it.

Comment: @AnubhavSaxena, I don't see `btnclick` in your HTML

Comment: @smerny         <div>
    <div id="popupdiv"title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none" >

    <table>
    <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="AddDepartmentButton" runat="server" Text="Save" 
                    onclick="AddDepartmentButton_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

    </div>

Comment: I don't see `btnclick` in that. Does it get generated? Try replacing your `click` line with `$('body').on("click", "#btnclick", function() {`

Comment: @smerny sorry but that btnclick is working fine my question is about AddDepartmentButton

Comment: @smerny,@khalid    Can you please check now now the whole code is there of my page and i am talking about AddDepartmentButton.

Answer (score 0):

What's with the orphan `<div>` tag on line 31?

Are you sure you've pasted the full markup?

Also, why is comment `<!-- <form id="form1">-->` on line 30? Do you have more than one `<form runat="server">` element?

**UPDATED:**

Just modify your dialog initialization as follows:

```
$('#btnclick').click(function () {
    var popup = $("#popupdiv").dialog({
        title: "Add Department",
        width: 430,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    popup.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
});
```

Comment: @ khalid       no Sir its not the full code i am going to change the code please take a look

Comment: can you please check it now i have submitted my whole page code.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Khalid now the button is working fine but the fields of popup window can only accessible by tab, mouse is not working on that popup window.

Comment: It is working fine with me. However, I can see that you're using jQuery 1.8.2, which has some issues with appendTo(). Try using jQuery 1.9.1 (or higher)

Answer (score -1):

This `display:none` does not only hide the `<div>`, but the page is acting like if there isn't it.
Use `visibility:hidden` if you want just to hide the `<div>`.

Comment: never heard of display:hidden.. maybe you mean visibility:hidden